# Spring Hateoas Causing an Exception "Cannot subclass final class void"

Tags: spring, groovy, spring-hateoas

I have the following controller logic (business garbage removed) that is generating an `IllegalArgumentException` with the message "Cannot subclass final class void".

package org.ghc.services.medicalsystem.controller

```
import com.google.common.collect.Maps
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController

import static org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilder.linkTo
import static org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilder.methodOn


@RestController
class ConsumerIdentificationController extends RestfulController {


    @RequestMapping (value  = '/identification/consumer/{consumerId}',
                     method = RequestMethod.GET)
    HttpEntity<HateoasResponse> consumerIdentificationRetrieval (@PathVariable final String consumerId) {
        def bogusResponse = Maps.newHashMapWithExpectedSize (1)
        bogusResponse.put ("bogus", "entry")
        def realResponse = new HateoasResponse (bogusResponse)
        realResponse.add (linkTo(methodOn (this.class).consumerIdentificationRetrieval (consumerId)).withSelfRel ())
        new ResponseEntity (realResponse, HttpStatus.OK)
    }

}

class HateoasResponse extends ResourceSupport {

    private Map<String,String> content


    @JsonCreator
    HateoasResponse (final Map<String, String> content) {
        this.content = content
    }
}
```

The non-HATEOAS portion of the method is working fine. Of note is that the controller is written in Groovy.

The stack trace for the error is:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class void
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:446)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:377)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:317)
    at org.springframework.hateoas.core.DummyInvocationUtils.getProxyWithInterceptor(DummyInvocationUtils.java:170)
    at org.springframework.hateoas.core.DummyInvocationUtils.access$100(DummyInvocationUtils.java:38)
    at org.springframework.hateoas.core.DummyInvocationUtils$InvocationRecordingMethodInterceptor.intercept(DummyInvocationUtils.java:100)
    at org.springframework.hateoas.core.DummyInvocationUtils$InvocationRecordingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DummyInvocationUtils.java:109)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy57.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Selector$MethodSelector.getMetaClass(Selector.java:531)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Selector$MethodSelector.setCallSiteTarget(Selector.java:942)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:211)
    at org.ghc.services.medicalsystem.controller.ConsumerIdentificationController.consumerIdentificationRetrieval(ConsumerIdentificationController.groovy:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:781)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:721)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.IndyInterface.selectMethod(IndyInterface.java:215)
    at org.ghc.cloudscale.logging.filter.CloudScaleLoggingFilter.doFilter(CloudScaleLoggingFilter.groovy:66)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.requestservlet.HystrixRequestContextServletFilter.doFilter(HystrixRequestContextServletFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1081)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The error is being thrown from the `linkTo()` method. Beyound that it gets into dynamic proxies that I'm not familiar with. Any suggestions are welcome as always!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running into a [known bug](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/issues/222) with Spring's HATEAOS and Groovy.  The only known workaround is to make your controller class statically compiled.